# CSS for SVG not working

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm following http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/svg_primer

Here is my `index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="circle.svg" alt="beatiful circle" width="200" height="400">
</body>
</html>
```

my `circle.svg` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%"/>
</svg>
```

my `style.css` :

```
circle {
    fill: red;
    fill-opacity: 0.9;
}
```

But my style won't applied to this circle. I only get black colored circle. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of mixing two different things there. Your CSS isn't targeting the image. You could just do this instead:

http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/AHwqh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

circle {
    fill: red;
    fill-opacity: 0.9;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just following example at http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/svg_primer. Sure i can style it this way. But, i'm curious why this isn't working.. :)

Comment: You can only use CSS to style SVG code embedded in your page. That tutorial you linked to doesn't deal with styling SVGs linked via the `img` element. If you want to link to a `.svg` file like that, you'll probably have to edit the file itself, editing the `<path>` to include a fill color.

Answer (score -1):

check out this link: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

> The problem with both  and background-image......you don't get to control the innards of the SVG with CSS...

one option is to use the tags, on your circle directly

```
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" fill="red" opacity="0.9"/>
```

Comment: Actually, you can precisely "control the innards of the SVG" (depending on your definition of "innards") with CSS.

Comment: hi torazaburo ... specifically OP is asking about importing svg via <img> tag as he wants to follow to follow wiki tutorials. In this instance, CSS files are not pulled. Therefore CSS is NOT the solution.

Comment: Actually, the OP *changed* his question to refer to an img. Originally, he had the SVG embedded in the HTML. My comment was in reference to that.

Comment: Okay! Weird tho I can't see whether he's made an edit